# I have a file that i am trying to read through and get the information out of, but i keep getting this

Tags: java

I have a file that i am trying to read through and get the information out of, but i keep getting this...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "flour"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at BakedItemList.readItemFile(BakedItemList.java:182)
at BakeryPart2.main(BakeryPart2.java:23)
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
     String scan = scanFile.next();
     char codeChar = scan.charAt(0);
     switch (codeChar) {

case 'P': case 'p':
           nameIn = scanLine.next();
           flavorIn = scanLine.next();
           quantityIn = Integer.parseInt(scanLine.next());
           crustCostIn = Double.parseDouble(scanLine.next());

           while (scanLine.hasNext()) {
              for (int i = 0; i < ingredientsIn.length
                    && ingredientsIn[i] != null; i++) {
                 ingredientsIn[i] = scanLine.next();
              }
           }

           item = new Pie(nameIn, flavorIn, quantityIn, crustCostIn,
                       ingredientsIn);
           itemList[itemCount] = item;
           itemCount++;
           break;
```

It reads in just fine until I get to crustCostIn.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception? Anyway, "flour" is not a number.

Comment: the error states what the problem is, second please format your code.

Comment: Peyton, read the doc on [`parseDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) (especially the *Throws* section)

Comment: @domdom after it gets the crust cost it is supposed to get the ingredients and thats what my while loop is for.

Comment: There is obviously a mismatch between the format of your input file and the way that you are reading it.  Clearly you are getting a non-numeric string ("flour") where you are expecting a floating point number.  If you need more help, provide a proper MCVE.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is so clearly, it's means that at this line   `crustCostIn = Double.parseDouble(scanLine.next());` the value of the `scanLine.next()` is 'flour'. That string cannot be parse to double. Please check your input file.